# distinct created_by and sum total_amount for each created_by

Tags: mysql

I am stuck with this.

I have two tables in my db (mysql) 1 is (i_mst) and 2 is (o_mst)

I have date column in i_mst and amount column in o_mst and created_by column in o_mst.

what I need is

```
distinct created_by and sum each created_by amount By i_mst date 

    BETWEEN '2013-01-01'
    AND '2013-08-01'
```

and return in single row.

to do this I am trying this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
o_mst.created_by
), o_mst.amount
FROM o_mst
LEFT JOIN i_mst ON i_mst.i_date
WHERE i_date
BETWEEN '2013-01-01'
AND '2013-08-01'
ORDER BY `o_mst`.`amount` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 5
```

It gives me multiple created_by ids and their amount.

I want to get distinct created_by rows and sum total_amount for each created_by row.

Help me if it is possible.

Thanks

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17717666/edit) your question and provide relevant sample data

Comment: also this has nothing to do with php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT o_mst.created_by, SUM(o_mst.amount)
FROM o_mst
INNER JOIN i_mst ON i_mst.inq_mst_id = o_mst.inq_mst_id 
WHERE i_date
BETWEEN '2013-01-01'
AND '2013-08-01'
GROUP BY o_mst.created_by DESC
LIMIT 0 , 5
```

Comment: hi there, thanks for help but it's giving me wrong calculation of amount.

Comment: if you do not have any common column in two tables, how u join them. Please add table structure and some data in sqlfiddle. They we will try to give a proper solution

Comment: changed my answer. Please check it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query

```
SELECT o_mst.created_by, SUM(o_mst.amount)
FROM o_mst
LEFT JOIN i_mst ON i_mst.i_date
WHERE i_date
BETWEEN '2013-01-01'
AND '2013-08-01'
GROUP BY o_mst.created_by
ORDER BY `o_mst`.`amount` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 5
```

Comment: hi there, thanks for help but it's giving me wrong calculation of amount.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
SELECT DISTINCT_VALUES.created_by, 
       SUM(DISTINCT_VALUES.amount)
 FROM
    (

   SELECT * 
   FROM o_mst
   LEFT JOIN i_mst ON i_mst.i_date
   WHERE i_date
   BETWEEN '2013-01-01'
   AND '2013-08-01'
    GROUP BY o_mst.created_by,  //.. all the columns that you want to merge
   ORDER BY `o_mst`.`amount` DESC
    LIMIT 0 , 5
) DISTINCT_VALUES
```